# What is on-topic for Homebrewing?

Tags: support

The reason I ask this is that there are quite a few questions about distillation, winemaking, meadmaking, cider making and just about everything in between. I looked a the [On-Topic](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) section for this stack and it says this is "Homebrew Stack Exchange is for dedicated home brewers and serious enthusiasts" then it says questions should be about:
Brewing processes
Equipment used in the brewing process
Brewed beverage appreciation
Trouble shooting your brewing problems

Since we are sticklers for the correct answer here on StackExchange wine, cider, booze are not "brewed". I am fine if we should broaden the scope of this stack but maybe we tell people to go over to https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/ What does everyone think?

Comment: I believe the site evolved through time, see: https://homebrew.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6/should-we-tag-questions-as-beer-brewing-or-wine-making

Answer (score 3):

The homebrewing topic is mainly about all alcohol produced by way of fermentation.

So cider, wine, beer and all other fermented product were and should continue to be accepted.  It would not be practicle to have one stack exchange about beer brewing, one about winemaking and another for cider making, etc.  They have a lot in common, it just makes sense to keep it all together.

The alcohol stakexchange is more about the finish product, not the making of.

Comment: I disagree. "Homebrewing" is for the art of making beer at home in a non-commercial setting. From Wikipedia: "Homebrewing is the brewing of beer on a small scale for personal, non-commercial purposes." I think we need to either expand the definition for this group or cut out all non-beer discussion. Obviously the first is the preferred route.

Comment: I agree with you about the definition of the word homebrewing, but this site is more than homebrewing.  If you look at all questions asked since the beginning you will see that 519 were about beer, 211 about cider, 172 about wine and 107 about mead.  Why is having someone ask about why his cider does not ferment bothers you?

Comment: It doesn't bother me, the definition for the group bothers me. Like I said, we should call out the fact that this is more than beer.